# How to test the retry policy for Service Bus dependency calls

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I have implemented the retry mechanism for service bus dependency calls in .Net Core API.

Below is the code I have used to create MessageSender object with retry policies.

```
var policy = new RetryExponential(
                        minimumBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                        maximumBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                        maximumRetryCount: 2);
        this.MessageSender = new MessageSender(serviceBusSettings.Connection, serviceBusSettings.MainQueueName,policy);
```

For that, I have followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/En-Us/Azure/Architecture/Best-Practices/Retry-Service-Specific#service-bus).

But I have no idea to test the Retry policy code in local whether it retried or not. whenever I have used the above object references of MessageSender?

Comment: What's the idea behind testing it? You don't trust the SDK? Or is there a different reason. Just as you don't need to test the file system to read a file, not sure what testing a customized retry policy will provide.

Comment: Just I want to confirm the SDK whether it is retrying or not. by disconnecting the internet connection while posting messages to service bus queue.

Comment: RetryPolicy will retry on `ServiceBusCommunicationException` which would cover the scenario you're referring to. Also, it will retry on any intermittent error.

Comment: I.e Ok, But how to log the retry attempts in Application Insights or any the logging source.

Comment: If you want custom log entries - you can't. You can't. `RetryPolicy` is not designed that way. Application Insights will log operations the SDK is attempting as that's "baked" into the SDK.